# Object Store Not getting shared b/w the mule runtimes

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, persistent-object-store

I have created two mule runtimes on different windows VM Machines. And Clustered them via Runtime Manager.

Created a Mule App with ObjectStore selecting persistent to true and deploy to cluster. I updated  the objectstore value on one server and when i tried to fetch from other its not returning the updated value.

What setting am i missing here ?

FYI: this is on Mule 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

To be shared between the cluster nodes the object store has to be set to non persistent. A persistent object store usually means it persist to disk. To share in a cluster it needs to be on memory. The cluster backend has a shared memory implementation that will share the object store.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on the Object Store. Especially in production.
Use it only for none essential data sharing.

It is easy to be corrupted when multiple requests come from different servers at the same moment.

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/IgnoreUnreliableObjectStorage.html